# Java array elements

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program to input a number `N`, which is an arbitrary number. Create an `array` having random numbers (each number being less than `100`) with length `N`. Now show all the numbers within the array as comma separated, 5 at a time.
E.g. The user enters value of `N` as `14`, and suppose the program creates an array like this:

```
[3,7,1,9,0,4,2,5,7,4,7,9,3,7]
```

Your final output should be

```
The array is: 3,7,1,9,0,4,2,5,7,4,7,9,3,7
Row1: 3,7,1,9,0
Row2: 4,2,5,7,4
Row3: 7,9,3,7
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Array
{   
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          
        int i,j=1,k=0,m;            
        System.out.print("Enter The Value:");           
        int n = scan.nextInt();         
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int[] result = new int[n];          
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {               
            result[i]=randomGenerator.nextInt(100);               
        }

        System.out.print("The array is:[");
        for (i = 1; i<= n; i++)
        {
            if(i%n!=0)
            {                   
                System.out.print(result[i-1]+",");              
            }
            else
            {                   
                 System.out.print(result[i-1]);
            }
        }          
        System.out.print("]");  

        int times = result.length/5;            
        for (k = 0; k <= times; k++)
        {               
            m = k+1;                
            System.out.print("\nRow "+m+":");

            for(; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if(j % 5 != 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(result[j-1]+",");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(result[j-1]);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I can write the program, but I have the following 2 problems:

1. Suppose the user inputs `N` as `14`. When the rows get printed, the last row shows up like this:

   ```
   Row3: 7,9,3,7,
   ```

   The last row has an additional comma that should be always removed.
2. When the N is input as multiple of 5, say 10, then we get an extra empty row printed. E.g. for 10, your program produces the following output:

   ```
   Enter The Value:10
   The array is:[52,63,82,89,89,29,84,57,37,52]
   Row 1:52,63,82,89,89
   Row 2:29,84,57,37,52
   Row 3:
   ```

This extra row should not occur in the output.

Comment: Check String#substring(int,int)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct number of rows, change

```
int times=result.length/5;
```

to

```
// this reduces times by one when result is divisible by 5
int times=(result.length%5==0)?(result.length/5-1):(result.length/5);
```

or, as KlitosKyriacou suggested, to

```
int times = (result.length-1)/5;
```

To avoid the extra `,` on the last line, change

```
      if(j%5!=0)
```

to

```
      if(j%5!=0 && j<n) // this avoid appending a `,` to the last number
```

Comment: A simplification: instead of using a conditional expression, just do `int times = (result.length-1)/5;`